# Отличие меток в C и C++

Tags: c++, c

Почему эта программа не компилируется в C++, но компилируется в C? https://godbolt.org/z/KsEs3zaK6

```
int main(){_:}
```

> error: expected primary-expression before '}' token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в стандарте C++ метки определены как

`attr(optional) identifier : statement`

а в C как

`attr-spec-seq(optional)(since C23) identifier :`

Т.е. в C++ после метки должно быть любое выражение, например:

```
int main(){  _: {} }
```

Предполагаю, нужно это из-за возможной неопределенности при использовании `::`.